# Asymptotic of a certain double sum involving binomial coefficients

Tags: co.combinatorics, asymptotics, binomial-coefficients

Consider sums of the form

$S(n)=\sum^{n}_{m=0}\sum^{m}_{k=1}2^{2k+m+1}{n-m+k+1 \choose 2k+2}{m \choose k}$

I am interested in the asymptotics of $S(n)$  as $n\to \infty$.

More precisely I would like to know whether it grows purely exponential in $n$ i.e.
whether there are numbers $c>0$ and $R>0$ such that

$R^{-1}\leq \lim \inf \frac{S(n)}{c^{n}}\leq \lim \sup \frac{S(n)}{c^{n}}\leq R$

Comment: It seems like Zeilberger's algorithm (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ZeilbergersAlgorithm.html) or W-Z pairs, also linked to on that page, might be helpful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The inner summation from $k=1$ looks a bit suspicious, since starting with $k=0$ appears to be more natural. So I assume that the inner summation starts with $k=0$ (the case of $k=1$ easily follows) and to avoid ambiguity I denote this sum by $S'(n)$.

The generating function for $S'(n)$ is
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} S'(n)\cdot x^n = \frac{2x}{(1-x)(1-4x-3x^2-2x^3)}.$$

It follows that $S'(n)$ grows proportionally to $\alpha^{-n}$, where $\alpha$ is the smallest (by absolute value) zero of the polynomial $1-4x-3x^2-2x^3$, that is
$$S'(n) \sim 4.7246^n.$$
More precisely, $S'(n) = 0.4580\cdot 4.7246^n +$ smaller terms.

UPDATE. For the sake of completeness, here is the generating function for $S(n)$:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} S(n)\cdot x^n = \frac{2x}{(1-x)(1-4x-3x^2-2x^3)} - \frac{2x}{(1-x)^3 (1-2x)}.$$
As Brendan McKay pointed out, the asymptotics for $S(n)$ is the same as for $S'(n)$.

Comment: And the $k=0$ alone gives a contribution at most $O(n^2 2^n)$ so it doesn't change the asymptotics.